Salary Negotiations delayed
I have completed three rounds of interviews with an MNC and received an email confirming that I cleared all three rounds, including both technical and HR interviews. However, I have not heard from the recruiter in the past ten days regarding salary negotiations. When I called today, the recruiter responded with a text stating, "Yes, we are working on your candidature and will reach out to you back."
Given this situation, is this a positive, negative, or neutral sign regarding my candidacy? What are the chances of being hired?

Can you confirm location - I am presuming this is India

Typo fix: The fact that you passed the interviews means they don't have a reason not to hire you. It does not mean that they won't find a better candidate. Until you have a signed contract, you do not have a job. Continue to apply and nterview elsewhere


I have completed three rounds of interviews with an MNC and received an email confirming that I cleared all three rounds, including both technical and HR interviews.

You do not happen an offer letter for the job as of yet. You will have to wait till you receive a hiring confirmation or a job offer letter from the company.

Given this situation, is this a positive, negative, or neutral sign regarding my candidacy? What are the chances of being hired?

Nobody else other than the hiring manager and the recruiters can tell what's on their mind.
It would be the best to wait for some more time to hear back from them. I'd advise you to continue exploring other available options.


Given this situation, is this a positive, negative, or neutral sign regarding my candidacy? What are the chances of being hired?

Hard to know without knowing the location. The level of bureaucracy required for hiring varies greatly across the world and even from company to company (which larger companies typically being slower). This being said, it's not unusual for a formal offer to take a couple of weeks to be issued. In some countries the offer is a legally relevant document and hence multiple sign offs (department head, finance, legal, HR, etc) are required which can take time.
Best you can do is

Keep pinging them once a week. Next time you ping them, ask about the expected time line.
Keep looking and interviewing until you have a formal offer or signed contract in hand.

